# How to create a FormControl name dynamic

Tags: angular

> here is the code I need to create a form-control dynamically
> hear this. products like an array, I need to create a form control based on the array (products), i am expected same like out put can anyone help me out this issue

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      SelectAll: new FormControl(''),
      genericTextBox: new FormControl(''),
      dateRangeTO: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      dateRangeFrom: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      products: this.fb.array(
        this.products.map((x) =>
          this.fb.group((x) =>
            this.form.addControl(x.name, new FormControl(''))
          )
        )
      ),
    });


products = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'AAA',
      displayName: 'aaaaaa',
      selected: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'BBB',
      displayName: 'bbbbbb',
      selected: false,
    },
 ];
```

**expected output for form control structure, console.log(this.form.value);**

```
{
  "genericTextBox": "",
  "dateRangeTO": "",
  "dateRangeFrom": "",
  "SelectAll": "",
  "products": {
    "AAA": "",
    "BBB": "",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```ts
ngOnInit() {

  const productFormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  this.products.forEach(product => productFormGroup.addControl(product.name, new FormControl('')));
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    SelectAll: new FormControl(''),
    genericTextBox: new FormControl(''),
    dateRangeTO: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    dateRangeFrom: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    products: productFormGroup,
  });

  console.log(this.form.value);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a need to do `this.fb.array` since what you want as per the output is a `FormGroup` and not an array. You can do the following:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      SelectAll: new FormControl(''),
      genericTextBox: new FormControl(''),
      dateRangeTO: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      dateRangeFrom: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      products: new FormGroup({})
   })
    this.populateProductForm();
    // get form value
    console.log(this.form.getRawValue())
}

// add the relevant interface for `product` array
populateProductForm(products: Array<any>): void {
  products.forEach((product) => {
    this.form.get('product')?.addControl(x.name, new FormControl(''))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create dynamic formControl name using bracket notation

**Try this:**

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    const groupProducts = this.products.reduce((acc, product) => {
      acc[product.name] = new FormControl('');
      return acc;
    }, {});
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      SelectAll: new FormControl(''),
      genericTextBox: new FormControl(''),
      dateRangeTO: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      dateRangeFrom: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      products: this.fb.group({
        ...groupProducts,
      }),
    });
  }
```